# How serious is the "DevTool failed to load source map" warning in Electron?

Tags: reactjs, electron, google-chrome-devtools, electron-builder

I'm working with electron react app and distributed it with the help of `electron-builder`.
Currently I'm following into this warning whenever I built, install and start my application:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for `file:///C:/Users/userName/AppData/Local/Programs/electron-app/resources/app.asar/build/preload.js.map`: Unexpected end of JSON input

When using the dev environment, I get this warning:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for `http://localhost:3000/preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

Which confuses me that it tries to do this access in the first place.

Now, based on many threads, this is a well-known issue. My question is though, how serious is this and what could I do to get rid of it? Because besides this warning, everything works fine.